# Substrate-node-template build fail

Tags: substrate

I followed this tutorial https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/.
I got the below error when run `cargo build --release`.
How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: update your rust toolchain and clean cargo first off. `rustup update && cargo clean` . What version of the node are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with prost is [Latest nightly does not build 0.7.0](https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost/issues/526). Either update prost version 0.8.0 or pin nightly to a version before rustc 1.56.0-nightly (50171c310 2021-09-01)

There will be an update shortly on the node template to fix this on the `latest` tag that includes [the patch needed](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/9676)